# Fastest way to compute entropy of each numpy array row?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, entropy, information-theory

I have a array in size MxN and I like to compute the entropy value of each row. What would be the fastest way to do so ?

Comment: entropy: -np.sum(probs * np.log2(probs))

Comment: By fastest, do you mean that you want an optimized version of it, or do you mean that you want something that fits in one line and is easy to read?

Comment: not easiest, fastest in terms of computation since I have a pretty large matrix, row iteration takes too much time.

Comment: Your first comment should be part of the question.  I interpret the question as "I have an array of probabilities `probs`, and I want the entropy of the rows."  If you don't already have probabilities, please clarify the question.

Answer (score 12):

[`scipy.special.entr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.entr.html) computes -x*log(x) for each element in an array.  After calling that, you can sum the rows.

Here's an example.  First, create an array `p` of positive values whose rows sum to 1:

```
In [23]: np.random.seed(123)

In [24]: x = np.random.rand(3, 10)

In [25]: p = x/x.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)

In [26]: p
Out[26]: 
array([[ 0.12798052,  0.05257987,  0.04168536,  0.1013075 ,  0.13220688,
         0.07774843,  0.18022149,  0.1258417 ,  0.08837421,  0.07205402],
       [ 0.08313743,  0.17661773,  0.1062474 ,  0.01445742,  0.09642919,
         0.17878489,  0.04420998,  0.0425045 ,  0.12877228,  0.1288392 ],
       [ 0.11793032,  0.15790292,  0.13467074,  0.11358463,  0.13429674,
         0.06003561,  0.06725376,  0.0424324 ,  0.05459921,  0.11729367]])

In [27]: p.shape
Out[27]: (3, 10)

In [28]: p.sum(axis=1)
Out[28]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])
```

Now compute the entropy of each row.  `entr` uses the natural logarithm, so to get the base-2 log, divide the result by `log(2)`.

```
In [29]: from scipy.special import entr

In [30]: entr(p).sum(axis=1)
Out[30]: array([ 2.22208731,  2.14586635,  2.22486581])

In [31]: entr(p).sum(axis=1)/np.log(2)
Out[31]: array([ 3.20579434,  3.09583074,  3.20980287])
```

If you don't want the dependency on `scipy`, you can use the explicit formula:

```
In [32]: (-p*np.log2(p)).sum(axis=1)
Out[32]: array([ 3.20579434,  3.09583074,  3.20980287])
```

Comment: My probabilities were all 0. To solve this I had to cast the denominator sum to float, e.g.,  p = x/float(x.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)). In case someone has the same problem.

Comment: `scipy.stats.entropy` also calculates the same value as `entr(p).sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 3):

As @Warren pointed out, it's unclear from your question whether you are starting out from an array of probabilities, or from the raw samples themselves. In my answer I've assumed the latter, in which case the main bottleneck will be computing the bin counts over each row.

Assuming that each vector of samples is relatively long, the fastest way to do this will probably be to use [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

```
import numpy as np

def entropy(x):
    """
    x is assumed to be an (nsignals, nsamples) array containing integers between
    0 and n_unique_vals
    """
    x = np.atleast_2d(x)
    nrows, ncols = x.shape
    nbins = x.max() + 1

    # count the number of occurrences for each unique integer between 0 and x.max()
    # in each row of x
    counts = np.vstack((np.bincount(row, minlength=nbins) for row in x))

    # divide by number of columns to get the probability of each unique value
    p = counts / float(ncols)

    # compute Shannon entropy in bits
    return -np.sum(p * np.log2(p), axis=1)
```

Although Warren's method of computing the entropies from the probability values using `entr` is slightly faster than using the explicit formula, in practice this is likely to represent a tiny fraction of the total runtime compared to the time taken to compute the bin counts.

Test correctness for a single row:

```
vals = np.arange(3)
prob = np.array([0.1, 0.7, 0.2])
row = np.random.choice(vals, p=prob, size=1000000)

print("theoretical H(x): %.6f, empirical H(x): %.6f" %
      (-np.sum(prob * np.log2(prob)), entropy(row)[0]))
# theoretical H(x): 1.156780, empirical H(x): 1.157532
```

Test speed:

```
In [1]: %%timeit x = np.random.choice(vals, p=prob, size=(1000, 10000))
   ....: entropy(x)
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 34.6 ms per loop
```

If your data don't consist of integer indices between 0 and the number of unique values, you can convert them into this format using [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
y = np.random.choice([2.5, 3.14, 42], p=prob, size=(1000, 10000))
unq, x = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
x.shape = y.shape
```

Comment: you might be able to save time by using `-np.dot(a, b)` in place of `-np.sum(a * b)`

Comment: @atomsmasher With `np.dot` I can't easily vectorize the entropy calculation over multiple rows. One way would be something like `-np.einsum('ij,ij->i', p, np.log2(p))`, although really you might as well just use `entr` for this part since it has an `axis` argument. Either way, the costly part is usually computing the bin counts.